# Index exceeds the number of array elements (1): while my array has enough number of elements

Tags: matlab

I want to simulate my function in MATLAB which is like this:

```
function z = AF(cur,theta,Rn, PHIn,phi)

FREQUENCY = 15e9;
LIGHT_SPEED = 3e8;
WAVELENGTH = LIGHT_SPEED / FREQUENCY;
K = 2 * pi / WAVELENGTH;
PHI = phi*pi/180;
RING_ELEMENT_NUM = [28,56,92];
theta = theta*pi/180;

i = round(1:round(sum(RING_ELEMENT_NUM)));
r1=Rn(i)
```

But it ended up with this error in the last line of above code:

```
Index exceeds the number of array elements (1).
```

I just put a breakpoint at the line to see the number of elements. "i" is swept from 1 to 176 with step 1. Moreover, "Rn" is a "struct 1*1" which embodies 176 elements in itself. So, how this error can take place in this particular example?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but what is the purpose of this `i = round(1:round(sum(RING_ELEMENT_NUM)));`? Why `round` twice? Why do it once? `..ELEMENT_NUM` suggests that vector contains only integers.

Comment: not important. let it go. it is repetitive. it does not have any effect on the error.

Comment: If `Rn` is a 1x1 struct, you cannot index it as `Rn(2)` or any other larger value, because there is only one element. Maybe you want to do `Rn.field_name(i)`?

Comment: “Let it go” @Stewie is trying to help. Please don’t be rude to people trying to help you.

Comment: without knowing Rn is impossible to tell, please share the code for it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example